# Atualizar node.js no ubuntu

Tags: node.js, electron

Não estou conseguindo atualizar o node.js no ubuntu.

Fiz a instalação, mas aqui aparece que foi instalado a versão:

> Node = v8.10.0
>
> Npm = v5.3.2

No site fala que a ultima versão é a 10.16, porque não foi instalado a ultima versão? Como atualizar para a ultima versão?

**Já segui vários tutoriais na internet, nenhum me ajudou a fazer a atualização.**

Estou tendo problema ao rodar uma aplicação minha que havia feito no windows. Agora tentando rodar no linux da esses erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E como fez a instalação?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss Segui instruções de vários sites, que me lembre agora, vendo no meu histórico foram esses sites: (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) e (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-o-node-js-no-ubuntu-16-04-pt) Obrigado.

Comment: No primeiro link há especificações de instalação para cada versão do Node. Qual delas utilizou?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Node.js v12.x: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -` e depois `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instale usando o nvm.

Execute esses comandos no terminal:

> sudo apt-get update

e depois:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev

Para baixar a instalação NVM que está no GitHub digite esse código no terminal:

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o 
  install_nvm.sh
```

Em seguida execute esse comando:

> bash install_nvm.sh

Depois disso, digite no terminal:

> source ~/.profile

Agora com NVM instalado, próximo passo é verificar as versões no NodeJs:

> nvm ls-remote

Depois só escolher a versão que deseja instalar:

> nvm install v12.13.1

Isso contorna o problema da instalação do nodejs sempre vir com a versão 8.